# SQL SERVER 2008 Stored procedure NOT update with CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I dont understand what's happening with my stored procedure when I want to execute it.
while it runs I can see values in ctr.custom and ctr.[name] .
AFTER The query executed successfully I'm tryin to SELECT data from CTR_Table and there NO available values in ctr.custom and ctr.[name] columns. ( empty data ).
CTR_Table table contain GOOD values!

What it`s wrong with my SP ?

HERE you have my SP :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[AddOrUpdateData]
as

DECLARE  @idP int;
SET @idP = 10; //always has a valid value

DECLARE @hCodePvd int;

//get all hotel codes
DECLARE item CURSOR FOR SELECT hotel_code FROM  AnotherTableData ;

OPEN item ;

FETCH NEXT FROM item  INTO @hCodePvd ;
```

//for each hotel code I want to update 1 row in CTR_Table table

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 


            UPDATE ctr SET              
                ctr.custom=r1.ccode_provider,
                ctr.[name]=r1.cname_provider                
            FROM
                CTR_Table ctr  INNER JOIN   AnotherTableData r1 ON ctr.[Standard] = r1.Code
            WHERE  r1.hcode =@hCodePvd AND ctr.IDP = @idP 


    FETCH NEXT FROM item  INTO @hCodePvd ;
END

CLOSE item ;
DEALLOCATE item ;
```

Comment: First off, i doubt you need a cursor to do this.  You are going to kill you performance with this stored proc.  Secondly, it looks like you are trying to update data in CTR_Table not select it.  Can you clarify what you are talking about?

Comment: I think you anonymized too much.  The proc as posted is seriously jacked.  Can you post the actual one?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code, here's what I understand what the tables involved might look like with sample data:

```
--CTR_table:
idP         standard   custom     name
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
10          Standard1  NULL       NULL
10          Standard2  NULL       NULL
10          Standard3  NULL       NULL
10          Standard4  NULL       NULL
10          Standard5  NULL       NULL

--AnotherTableData:
hotel_code  hcode       code       ccode_provider cname_provider
----------- ----------- ---------- -------------- --------------
1           1           Standard1  ccode1         cname1
2           2           Standard2  ccode2         cname2
3           3           Standard3  ccode3         cname3
4           4           Standard4  ccode4         cname4
5           5           Standard5  ccode5         cname5
```

Note: I was expecting that `hotel_code` belonged to one table and `hcode` belonged to the other table so that these columns serve as a join point for the two tables. However, the code shows that both these fields belong to the same table. The two fields have to be equal for a row on `AnotherTableData` to be used in the update.

The following query will update `CTR_table` without using cursors:

```
DECLARE  @idP int;
SET @idP = 10; --always has a valid value

UPDATE CTR_table
SET
    CTR_table.custom = AnotherTableData.ccode_provider,
    CTR_table.[name] = AnotherTableData.cname_provider
FROM CTR_table
INNER JOIN AnotherTableData
    ON CTR_table.idP = @idp
    AND CTR_table.standard = AnotherTableData.code
    AND AnotherTableData.hotel_code = AnotherTableData.hcode
```

After the update, the `custom` and `name` fields on `CTR_table` will be populated:

```
SELECT * FROM CTR_table

idP         standard   custom     name
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
10          Standard1  ccode1     cname1
10          Standard2  ccode2     cname2
10          Standard3  ccode3     cname3
10          Standard4  ccode4     cname4
10          Standard5  ccode5     cname5
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [MERGE statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). It's a tad complicated, but you'll be able to run typical "update, add of not exists" scenario's in a single query.

Performance will go through the roof.